# How to automatically show USB camera or memory stick contents in Icewm?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, camera, lightweight

I normally use a very lightweight Linux setup.  No desktop like Gnome or KDE, just Icewm as the windows manager and nothing else that normal users might consider essential.  Well, I do need a file manager - I use Thunar.

Recently I've been trying Gnome. Whenever I shove a memory stick into a USB port, or connect my digital camera, it can automatically pop up a file manager showing all the goodies on that device.    KDE does this too.   I like this.  Although quick at the command line, I like not having to go sudo to mount the device and all that.

If I want to stick with a lightweight setup using Icewm+Thunar, is there something non-huge I can install to make external devices fire up a Thunar window, or otherwise make access to the contents brainlessly easy?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the customary tool used here is [autofs](http://www.autofs.org/). You don't specify your Linux distribution, but on Debian, the corresponding package is autofs5.